# Wpf DataGrid ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader" with custom header

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF table that has a custom header (based on a StackPanel) which includes a button that displays and handles setting the units of for the column. Which works nicely, however I want to be able to copy the data to clipboard including headers.

```
<DataGrid ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader"
...
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Some Header" Binding={Binding Path=SomeValue}/>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding={Binding Path=OtherValue, Converter="{StaticResource unitsConverter}">
<DataGridTextColumn.Header>
<StackPanel>
<TextBlock Text="Period" />
<Button ... />
</Stackpanel>
```

The problem is that columns with the custom header copy to the clipboard as

```
SomeHeader System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel
v1         33
```

Is there a way to change what text is printed for the header when a custom header is used?

Answer (score 10):

I poked around for a solution then ended up subclassing my custom header control just to override the `ToString()` so that `ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader"` would copy the correct text.

In my case I used an image in my header:

```
class HeaderImage : Image
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Tag.ToString();
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
 <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
     <elements:HeaderImage Source="..\Resources\skull.png" Width="15" Tag="Deprecated"/>
 </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
```

Now the copy/paste data has "Deprecated" instead of `System.Windows.Controls.Image`. I'm sure you could do the same with the `StackPanel`. I used Tag as header text since it was convenient

Comment: Thanks @xerous and yes it does indeed work for a StackPanel as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution to this issue when using a HeaderTemplate that had a text block in it.  In my case I solved the issue with an attached property.  You can see that I just take the text from the header template, and set it onto the header property.  This way clipboard copy mode IncludeHeader works as expected.

```
 /// <summary>  
 /// WPF Data grid does not know what is in a header template, so it can't copy it to the clipboard when using ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader".  
 /// This attached property works with a header template that includes one TextBlock. Text content from the templates TextBlock is copied to the  
 /// column header for the clipboard to pick up.  
 /// </summary>  
public static class TemplatedDataGridHeaderText  
{  
 private static readonly Type OwnerType = typeof(TemplatedDataGridHeaderText);  
 public static readonly DependencyProperty UseTextFromTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("UseTextFromTemplate", typeof(bool), OwnerType, new PropertyMetadata(false, OnHeaderTextChanged));  
 public static bool GetUseTextFromTemplate(DependencyObject obj)  
 {  
   return (bool)obj.GetValue(UseTextFromTemplateProperty);  
 }  
 public static void SetUseTextFromTemplate(DependencyObject obj, bool value)  
 {  
   obj.SetValue(UseTextFromTemplateProperty, value);  
 }  
 private static void OnHeaderTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)  
 {  
   var textColumn = d as DataGridTextColumn;  
   if (textColumn == null) return;  
   if (textColumn.HeaderTemplate == null) return;  
   var headerTemplateTexblockText = textColumn.HeaderTemplate.LoadContent().GetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty).ToString();  
   textColumn.Header = headerTemplateTexblockText;  
 }  
}
```

The xaml would look like this....

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding }" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">  
 <DataGrid.Columns>  
   <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FlowRate.UserValue, StringFormat=N3}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource FlowRate}"  
             attachedProperties:TemplatedDataGridHeaderText.UseTextFromTemplate="True"/>  
   <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Pressure.UserValue, StringFormat=N3}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource Pressure}"  
             attachedProperties:TemplatedDataGridHeaderText.UseTextFromTemplate="True"/>  
 </DataGrid.Columns>
```

More info can be found here... http://waldoscode.blogspot.com/2014/08/issue-using-wpf-datagrid-columnheader.html

Answer (score 0):

I used the alternative AttachedProperty in GetFuzzy's link http://waldoscode.blogspot.com/2014/08/issue-using-wpf-datagrid-columnheader.html. The author (Don) created a AttachedProperty as follows (with a couple of small mods of my own):

```
/// <summary>  
/// Allows binding a property to the header text. Works with the clipboard copy mode - IncludeHeaders.  
/// </summary>  
public static class DataGridHeaderTextAttachedProperty  
{  
  private static readonly Type OwnerType = typeof(DataGridHeaderTextAttachedProperty);  
  public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HeaderText", typeof(string), OwnerType, new PropertyMetadata(OnHeaderTextChanged));  

  public static string GetHeaderText(DependencyObject obj)  
  {  
    return (string)obj.GetValue(HeaderTextProperty);  
  }  

  public static void SetHeaderText(DependencyObject obj, string value)  
  {  
    obj.SetValue(HeaderTextProperty, value);  
  }  

  private static void OnHeaderTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)  
  {  
    var column = d as DataGridColumn;  
    if (column == null) return;  
    column.Header = GetHeaderText(column);  
  }  
}
```

I wasn't able to get it to work when setting the Column.Header directly but was able to get it to work with the HeaderTemplate as below:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn ...
                        ui:DataGridHeaderTextAttachedProperty.HeaderText="Some Text">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Data="{StaticResource SomeGeometry}" ... />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>

    ...
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

THANKS GetFuzzy FOR AN EXCELLENT BLOG POST!